# grails FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin

Environment details:
MongoDB
Windows 10
Grails 3.0.12
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)

Application.yml

```
    ---
    grails:
        profile: web
        codegen:
            defaultPackage: org.samatvam
    info:
        app:
            name: '@info.app.name@'
            version: '@info.app.version@'
            grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
    spring:
        groovy:
            template:
                check-template-location: false

    ---
    grails:
        mime:
            disable:
                accept:
                    header:
                        userAgents:
                            - Gecko
                            - WebKit
                            - Presto
                            - Trident
            types:
                all: '*/*'
                atom: application/atom+xml
                css: text/css
                csv: text/csv
                form: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                html:
                  - text/html
                  - application/xhtml+xml
                js: text/javascript
                json:
                  - application/json
                  - text/json
                multipartForm: multipart/form-data
                pdf: application/pdf
                rss: application/rss+xml
                text: text/plain
                hal:
                  - application/hal+json
                  - application/hal+xml
                xml:
                  - text/xml
                  - application/xml
        urlmapping:
            cache:
                maxsize: 1000
        controllers:
            defaultScope: singleton
        converters:
            encoding: UTF-8
        views:
            default:
                codec: html
            gsp:
                encoding: UTF-8
                htmlcodec: xml
                codecs:
                    expression: html
                    scriptlets: html
                    taglib: none
                    staticparts: none
    ---
    hibernate:
        cache:
            queries: false
            use_second_level_cache: true
            use_query_cache: false
            region.factory_class: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'

    endpoints:
        jmx:
            unique-names: true

    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:

    environments:
        development:
            grails:
                mongodb:
                    host: "localhost"
                    port: 27017
                    username: "blah"
                    password: "blah"
                    databaseName: "emrDB"
                    connectionString: "mongodb://blah:blah@localhost:27017/emrDB"

        test:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: create-drop
                url: mongodb://blah:blah@localhost:27017/emrDB;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        production:
            dataSource:
                dbCreate: update
                url: jdbc:h2:./prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
                properties:
                    jmxEnabled: true
                    initialSize: 5
                    maxActive: 50
                    minIdle: 5
                    maxIdle: 25
                    maxWait: 10000
                    maxAge: 600000
                    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                    validationQuery: SELECT 1
                    validationQueryTimeout: 3
                    validationInterval: 15000
                    testOnBorrow: true
                    testWhileIdle: true
                    testOnReturn: false
                    jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                    defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

------------------------------build.gradle------------------------------------

```
buildscript {
    ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    }
    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0'
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate:4.3.10.5"
    }
    }

    plugins {
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "0.5.4.RELEASE"
    }

    version "0.1"
    group "org.emr"

    apply plugin: "spring-boot"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "asset-pipeline"
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
    apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

    ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
    gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
    }

    assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    }

    repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    maven {url "http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/"}
    }

    dependencyManagement {
    imports {
    mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
    }
    applyMavenExclusions false
    }

    dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    //compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    //compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"

    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"

    //--------project-plugin-start------------------------//
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.0.RC1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:calendar:1.2.1"
    //compile "org.grails.plugins:jquery-ui:1.10.4"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:joda-time:1.5"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:rest:0.8"
    //compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
    //runtime "org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1"
    runtime "org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.7"
    runtime 'org.grails.plugins:twitter-bootstrap:3.3.5'
    //build "org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.52.1"
    compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.0.RC1"

    //compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"
    // runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'

    //----------------------------------------------------//
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
    }
```

-------------------error---------------------------------

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
Exception in thread "main"      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source) [grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133) [groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.emr.Application.main(Application.groovy:8) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75) ~[grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53) ~[grails-core-3.0.12.jar:3.0.12]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.notNull(Assertions.java:37) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.<init>(MongoCredential.java:233) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.MongoCredential.createCredential(MongoCredential.java:106) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.1.1.jar:na]
        at org.grails.datastore.gorm.mongo.bean.factory.MongoClientFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MongoClientFactoryBean.java:145) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb-5.0.0.RC1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568) ~[spring-beans-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        ... 50 common frames omitted
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:199)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:54)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:353)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:342)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at org.emr.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.initialize(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:75)
        at org.grails.transaction.TransactionManagerPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(TransactionManagerPostProcessor.java:53)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1591)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1559)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatastore': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongo' while setting bean property 'mongo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: source can not be null
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1475)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220)
```

Comment: Where's the exception?

Comment: in short this is the error i am facing. I think some thing is messed up in appliaction.yml file.      ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTransactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoDatastore' while setting bean property 'datastore';

Comment: Why is that different than the except you just posted in the question? Where is the bean named 'mongoDatastore' defined?

Comment: Hi Mark: i am using mongodb gorm plugin. I dont think mongoDatastore need to be set by the user. But i am sure something is wrong with application.yml file

Comment: when do you see this error? which command do you start application or is it external container?

Comment: I start the app using: grails run-app command. I use default tomcat server which is available in framework.

Comment: The real error is the `IllegalArgumentException` about the `source` that is `null`. Is your datasource definition correct? Have you followed the mongodb plugin documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in the GORM plugin. It doesn't seem to recognize the databaseName property. It does seem to work if you use ONLY the connection string.

connectionString: "mongodb://username:password@host:port/databaseName"

For details: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/